# JavaFX editable table cell having display errors

Tags: javafx, tableview

Editing the question as per Brian's suggestion:

I have now trimmed it down to just a single integer column.
I am simply not able to find the problem in the code. THe values show up only when the columns are selected once for edit. 
Please suggest of i am making some mistake in the EditingCell class.

The single classfile code that i am trying is as follows.

```
package javafxtest;


import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
//import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author balz
 */
public class UploadTemplateController extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        MasterUploadParameter objMasterUploadParameter=new MasterUploadParameter();
        MasterUploadParameter objMasterUploadParameter1=new MasterUploadParameter();
        MasterUploadParameter objMasterUploadParameter2=new MasterUploadParameter();

        final ObservableList<MasterUploadParameter> tableContent =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList
            (
                objMasterUploadParameter,
                objMasterUploadParameter1,
                objMasterUploadParameter2
            );

        TableColumn ColumnID = new TableColumn();
        ColumnID.setText("columnId");
        ColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("columnId"));

        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory =
                new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {

                    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {

                        return new EditingCell();
                    }
                };
        ColumnID.setCellFactory(cellFactory);




        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.setItems(tableContent);
        //Enabling editing
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(ColumnID);
        root.getChildren().add(tableView); 
    }

    private void updateObservableListProperties(TableColumn<MasterUploadParameter, Integer> ColumnFieldNo, TableColumn<MasterUploadParameter, Boolean> ColumnLPad, TableColumn<MasterUploadParameter, Integer> ColumnStarting, TableColumn<MasterUploadParameter, Integer> ColumnEnding, TableColumn<MasterUploadParameter, String> ColumnSheetID, TableColumn<MasterUploadParameter, Integer> ColumnID, TableColumn<MasterUploadParameter, Integer> ColumnStartingRow, TableColumn<MasterUploadParameter, Integer> ColumnEnding0) {
        ColumnFieldNo.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<MasterUploadParameter, Integer>>() {           
            @Override public void handle(CellEditEvent<MasterUploadParameter, Integer> t) {
                ((MasterUploadParameter) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setcolumnId(new SimpleIntegerProperty(t.getNewValue()));
            }
        });


    }
    public static class MasterUploadParameter {
        private SimpleIntegerProperty columnId;
        public SimpleIntegerProperty columnIdProperty() {return columnId;}
        public void setcolumnId(SimpleIntegerProperty columnId) {this.columnId = columnId;}

        public MasterUploadParameter() {
            this.columnId=new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        }
    }
    // EditingCell - for editing capability in a TableCell
    public static class EditingCell extends TableCell<MasterUploadParameter, Integer> {
        private TextField textField;

        public EditingCell() {
            System.out.println("find value of textField: "+textField);
        }

        @Override public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            System.out.println("find value of textField: "+textField);
            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        @Override public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            System.out.println("find value of update: "+empty+item);
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
            textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {                
                @Override public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }

    } 


}
```

Comment: I am not able to send all of the code,due to restrictions in the webpage.
The actual issue is that, the fields look blank initially, after double clicking on them, they show the value stored in them.
Unable to debug even after help in the forum earlier discussions.

Comment: Make a small example with just one column, no FXML, and keep the editingCell.  It's too hard to figure out.  You're missing the `@Override` on the `public void updateItem`, but I doubt that's the problem.  Make sure your 'MasterUploadParameter' class has the getters and setters and not just the variables.

Comment: Dear Brian,
Thanks for the inputs.I have still not been able to get it working. I have affixed the source code as a single class file.
And if i comment out //ColumnID.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
it displays contents correctly. Can you please help me with the last class of this code?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks Brian, I figured it out. I am using Columns of integers and Strings. When the EditingCell (class) is extending TableCell, i was doing String validation for Integer by typecasts, which turned out to be incorrect. I have created another class for string types.
i.e 
public static class EditingCellString extends TableCell<MasterUploadParameter, String>

Comment: @Fishbed is your problem solved then? If it is you can answer your question yourself to let people know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need separate editing cell types.  You can use the col.setOnEditCommit method

Just use `public static class EditingCell extends TableCell{`  with no type information.  (I guess that's why you left out @override before.)

Change the updateItem to `@Override public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {`

Then whenever you call commitEdit use a string (all textfields have strings anyway).  `commitEdit(textField.getText())`

Then for each column depending, on the type you can commit the edit however you want.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
//import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author balz
 */
public class UploadTemplateController extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        MasterUploadParameter objMasterUploadParameter=new MasterUploadParameter();
        MasterUploadParameter objMasterUploadParameter1=new MasterUploadParameter();
        MasterUploadParameter objMasterUploadParameter2=new MasterUploadParameter();

        final ObservableList<MasterUploadParameter> tableContent =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList
            (
                objMasterUploadParameter,
                objMasterUploadParameter1,
                objMasterUploadParameter2
            );

        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                return new EditingCell();
            }
        };

        TableColumn ColumnID = new TableColumn();
        ColumnID.setText("columnId");
        ColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("columnId"));
        ColumnID.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        ColumnID.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<MasterUploadParameter, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<MasterUploadParameter, String> evt) {
                try {
                    evt.getTableView().getItems().get(evt.getTablePosition().getRow())
                            .columnId.set(Integer.parseInt(evt.getNewValue()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
                    //do whatever if a non int is entered
                }
            }
        });

        TableColumn columnDesc = new TableColumn("Desc");
        columnDesc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("desc"));
        columnDesc.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        columnDesc.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<MasterUploadParameter, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<MasterUploadParameter, String> evt) {
                evt.getTableView().getItems().get(evt.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        .desc.set(evt.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.setItems(tableContent);
        //Enabling editing
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(ColumnID, columnDesc);
        root.getChildren().add(tableView); 
    }

    public static class MasterUploadParameter {
        private SimpleIntegerProperty columnId;
        public SimpleIntegerProperty columnIdProperty() {return columnId;}

        private StringProperty desc;
        public StringProperty descProperty() {return desc;}

        public MasterUploadParameter() {
            this.columnId=new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
            this.desc = new SimpleStringProperty("hi");
        }
    }
    // EditingCell - for editing capability in a TableCell
    public static class EditingCell extends TableCell{
        private TextField textField;

        @Override public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.selectAll();
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textField.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();

            try {
                setText(getItem().toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            System.out.println("find value of update: "+empty+item);
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
            textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {                
                @Override public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }

    } 


}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. That does the business.
if (isObjectInteger(Object o))
OR
try{}catch(NumberFormatException e){}
Which of the 2 would be better to handle the String - integer mismatch?

Also, lets say, there are 8 columns in the table ~ and 8 mapped variables in the entity class. If 1 integer column is tried to be updated to string, can i find out the name of the column that is caused this exception?

Comment: Well a string is never an int so you'd have to convert it first anyway.  Also, I've never seen that code, I'd use `o instanceof type`.  The column name can be accessed in onEditCommit by `evt.getTableColumn().getText()`.