# Javafx reuse same cellfactory for different types

Tags: java, javafx

I have two columns in a TableView, one holds integers and the other holds strings.

```
colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyCellData, String>("id"));
colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyCellData, String>("name"));
```

The MyCellData class holds the information for the rows

```
public static class MyCell extends TableCell<MyCellData, Object> {

    public MyCell() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        if (item != null) {
            setText((String) item);
        }
    }

}
```

The MyCell class above is a basic cellfactory. Is it possible to use it for both columns as seen in the first snippet of code, despite one being for integers and the other for strings?

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21365915/2855515

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution that is similar to yours. I have answered the question here with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which seems to work great.

I changed

```
public static class MyCell extends TableCell<MyCellData, Object> {
```

to

```
public static class MyCell<E> extends TableCell<MyCellData, E> {
```

so I can create a new CellFactory like so

```
Callback<TableColumn<MyCellData, Integer>, TableCell<MyCellData, Integer>> c2 = new Callback<TableColumn<MyCellData, Integer>, TableCell<MyCellData, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<MyCellData, Integer> call(TableColumn<MyCellData, Integer> param) {
                return new MyCell<Integer>();
            }
        };
```

Changing Integer to String for a column containing Strings!